# How to get the ControllerContext instance, where the exception comes from in the Error action in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

**My Startup.cs:**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // ...

    // If exception occurs -> execute /Error/Index
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/Index");
       
    // ...
}
```

**My Error Controller:**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var exceptionFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
        if (exceptionFeature == null || exceptionFeature.Error == null)
        {
            new Exception("Please configure app.UseExceptionHandler(\"/Error/Index\");");
        }

        // TODO:

        // How can I get the ControllerContext instance that the Exception comes from

        return View();
    }
}
```

**TestController:**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        throw new Exception("Sample error");
    }
}
```

If I access: http://localhost:12345/MyApp/Test/Index
-> "Sample Error" will be generated
-> The ErrorController/index will get executed
-> I need to access the ControllerContext of the TestController (NOT ErrorController) in the ErrorController/index

Any helps? Thank you!

Comment: The easiest way to do this, is create a custom Exception that has a Context property!

Comment: @AbdelkrimBournane: That solution works but it won't work with exceptions come from other libs.